# How to use glewInit function from glew.h with QT?

Tags: qt, opengl, glew

I coded a small QT application (version 5.1.0 (msvc2012_64_opengl), Add-in 1.2.2) in Visual studio 2012. I started with GLU.h include and the program works perfectly. But I want to implement some functions from glew.h. The first thing to do in this case is to call the 'glewInit' method a the top of the 'initializeGL' QT method. But I have the following error :

```
error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol __glewInit
```

But I noticed that the code is well exectuted without glewInit but with the #include "glew.h" and not #include "glu.h". So the linkage in the project properties are correct (glu32.lib). So the problem seems to comes from the interaction between QT and my own include of glew.h (I want to say I use glew.h since lots of time without any problem but NOT with QT).

Here's my c++ header file :

```
#include <gl/glew.h>
#define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2
#include <QGLWidget>
//#include <QtOpenGL\qgl.h>
//#include <qtopengl.h>

class HSGLWidget : public QGLWidget {

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit HSGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        virtual ~HSGLWidget();

    protected:
        virtual void initializeGL();
        virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height);
        virtual void paintGL();

        virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent); /// From QWidget

    private:
        void _onSetup();

    private:
        QTimer  *_timer;
};
```

My C++ source file :

```
 #include "HSGLWidget.hpp"
    #define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2

    HSGLWidget::HSGLWidget(QWidget *parent) 
        :  QGLWidget(parent) {
        this->_onSetup();

    }

HSGLWidget::~HSGLWidget() {
}

void HSGLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glewInit();
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.20f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void HSGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {

    if (height == 0)
        height = 1;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void HSGLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3d(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

And my main :

    #include <QApplication>
    #include "HSGLWidget.hpp"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        HSGLWidget myWin;
        myWin.show();
        return app.exec();
    }
```

I tried to use #define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2 declaration just below my glew.h include definition but it still the same thing. I 'm really lost in front of this situation.
Does anyone can help me?

Comment: "o the linkage in the project properties are correct (glu32.lib)" You need to linke with **glew** as well, you know.

Comment: I,ve already linked with glew32.lib too. All my linkages are corrects. My program works with glew but without glewinit call.

Comment: IIRC you won't get a linker error unless you actually reference a symbol defined in the glew lib (so no error unless you actually have a call to glewInit in your source). That error is pretty clear, the linker cannot find the glew library, you should recheck your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Linking failure? 
Project options-> Linker-> Input

Put there the glew(For example on my project: glew32.lib)

Hope this helped you